# How hide a block for a route in ember when go to a sub-route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember 2 and the things for Ember beginners is a pretty confuse. I've the following routes.

`queries\`

`queries\booking`

And I my `router.js` is

```
this.route('queries', function() {
    this.route('booking');
}
```

The queries template have some informations, and booking template is more complex. When user go to booking template I want hide some parts from queries template.

How I do this in Ember 2.0 or how I can access in a helper the route to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a loading template that will be shown if a promise in the beforeModel, model, afterModels takes significant time to resolve.

You could use this to glass pane or show a spinner, etc.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Alternatively, you could use the willTransition, didTransition hooks in your route instance.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html

Comment: Ok! But when I do this I will duplicate or lost my navigation. Cause in Application template I 've a login page.

Comment: Are you using the `{{outlet}}` tag to render the content of your route?  You can also use nested outlet tags if you wanted to have main nav and then sub-nav for a particular set of routes.



You are probably going to need to move your login page out of the application template as it's not sustainable to leave it in there.  It will need to be a separate view/route that you transition to if a user is not authenticated.  I recommend the ember-simple-auth addon to do this work for you.

Comment: I'll use ember-simple-auth.

I use `{{outlet}}` to render nested routes. But sometimes I want hide some tags from de main Route.

Comment: If switching out the template with a loading template won't suit for your use cae, you may be able to use the `loading` action and take custom action.  For instance, if you have to go above or outside of your dom hierarchy, you may need to store some state in a service that can be used from both places.  

This article explains loading states very well:  
http://balinterdi.com/2014/06/18/indicating-progress-loading-routes-in-ember-dot-js.html

Comment: I change to switching templates. Was more simple. thanks